# Can anyone suggest a more generic way to convert HashMaps to/from Strings?

Tags: apex, force.com

I'm storing HashMaps as Strings in long TextAreas (works up to 131,072 characters).  Can anyone suggest an improved or more generic way over what's below?  I know I could have the fromString method return an Object but then I have to cast the return Object to a particular Map in the code each time.  I'm using some of [MapUtils.cls](https://code.google.com/p/apex-lang/source/browse/trunk/eclipse-project/src/classes/MapUtils.cls)

```
private final static String HEADER_STRING_TO_STRING  = '<MapUtils:STOS{';
private final static String HEADER_STRING_TO_DOUBLE  = '<MapUtils:STOD{';
private final static String HEADER_STRING_TO_INTEGER = '<MapUtils:STOI{';
private final static String HEADER_STRING_TO_LONG    = '<MapUtils:STOL{';

private final static String TRAILER = '}>';
private final static String KV_SEPARATOR = '=';
private final static String RECORD_SEPARATOR = ';';

global static String toString(Map<String,String> theMap) {
    return HEADER_STRING_TO_STRING + joinMap(theMap, KV_SEPARATOR, RECORD_SEPARATOR) + TRAILER;
}

global static String toString(Map<String,Double> theMap) {
    Map<String,String> newMap = new Map<String,String>();
    for (String key : theMap.keySet() ){
        Double val = theMap.get(key);
        newMap.put(key, String.valueOf(val));   
    }
    return HEADER_STRING_TO_DOUBLE + joinMap(newMap, KV_SEPARATOR, RECORD_SEPARATOR) + TRAILER;
}

 global static String toString(Map<String,Integer> theMap) {
    Map<String,String> newMap = new Map<String,String>();
    for (String key : theMap.keySet() ){
        Integer val = theMap.get(key);
        newMap.put(key, String.valueOf(val));   
    }
    return HEADER_STRING_TO_INTEGER + joinMap(newMap, KV_SEPARATOR, RECORD_SEPARATOR) + TRAILER;
 }

 global static String toString(Map<String,Long> theMap) {
    Map<String,String> newMap = new Map<String,String>();
    for (String key : theMap.keySet() ) {
        Long val = theMap.get(key);
        newMap.put(key, String.valueOf(val));   
    }
    return HEADER_STRING_TO_LONG + joinMap(newMap, KV_SEPARATOR, RECORD_SEPARATOR) + TRAILER;
}

global static Map<String,String> fromStringStoS(String s){
    if (!s.startsWith(HEADER_STRING_TO_STRING)){
        throw new MyException('Map does not begin with '+HEADER_STRING_TO_STRING);
    }
    Map<String,String> m = new Map<String,String>();
    Integer i = s.length();
    String y = s.substring(HEADER_STRING_TO_STRING.length(), i - TRAILER.length());
    String[] z = y.split(RECORD_SEPARATOR);
    for (String e : z ){
        String[] entry = e.split(KV_SEPARATOR);
        String key = entry[0];
        String value = entry[1];
        m.put(key, value);
    }
    return m;
}

global static Map<String,Double> fromStringStoD(String s){
    if (!s.startsWith(HEADER_STRING_TO_DOUBLE)){
        throw new MyException('Map does not begin with '+HEADER_STRING_TO_DOUBLE);
    }
    Map<String,Double> m = new Map<String,Double>();
    Integer i = s.length();
    String y = s.substring(HEADER_STRING_TO_DOUBLE.length(), i - TRAILER.length());
    String[] z = y.split(RECORD_SEPARATOR);
    for (String e : z ){
        String[] entry = e.split(KV_SEPARATOR);
        String key = entry[0];
        Double value = Double.valueOf(entry[1]);
        m.put(key, value);
    }
    return m;
}

global static Map<String,Integer> fromStringStoI(String s){
    if (!s.startsWith(HEADER_STRING_TO_INTEGER)){
        throw new MyException('Map does not begin with '+HEADER_STRING_TO_INTEGER);
    }
    Map<String,Integer> m = new Map<String,Integer>();
    Integer i = s.length();
    String y = s.substring(HEADER_STRING_TO_INTEGER.length(), i - TRAILER.length());
    String[] z = y.split(RECORD_SEPARATOR);
    for (String e : z ) {
        String[] entry = e.split(KV_SEPARATOR);
        String key = entry[0];
        Integer value = Integer.valueOf(entry[1]);
        m.put(key, value);
    }
    return m;
}

  global static Map<String,Long> fromStringStoL(String s){
    if (!s.startsWith(HEADER_STRING_TO_LONG)){
        throw new MyException('Map does not begin with '+HEADER_STRING_TO_LONG);
    }
    Map<String,Long> m = new Map<String,Long>();
    Integer i = s.length();
    String y = s.substring(HEADER_STRING_TO_LONG.length(), i - TRAILER.length());
    String[] z = y.split(RECORD_SEPARATOR);
    for (String e : z) {
        String[] entry = e.split(KV_SEPARATOR);
        String key = entry[0];
        Integer value = Integer.valueOf(entry[1]);
        m.put(key, value);
    }
    return m;
}
```

Comment: Dumb question, but why not just store the data as JSON instead of this custom format? The built in methods should be noticeably faster and there would be less code to maintain.

Comment: Yes I will change it to JSON encoding actually.